# How can I fix the error in Retrofit 2? I have an error sending a request

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I don't understand where the error is. My project has REGISTER section. I need to get the email and send it to AuthService.

This image shows the error:

[image]

This is my AuthService:

[image]

This is a sample request from Postman:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception message said :

> for dynamic query parameters use @Query

`@Path` is used for replacing a URL path segment, not for adding query parameters.

Your function should be something like this:

```
@GET("/auth/send-email")
fun sendEmail(@Query("email") email: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it as follows:

```
@GET("/auth/send-email")
fun sendEmail(@Query("email") email: String)
```